# postfix/sasl/pam (mysql) auth error

Tags: postfix, smtp, pam, sasl

I've followed tutorial on http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/ to set up an email server, and most of it works (after switching from Courier to Dovecot). Just not sending email through SMTP. Sending with `sendmail` works.

This is what I see in `/var/log/auth.log` when I try to send an email with Thunderbird:

```
May 22 18:45:59 myserver postfix/submission/smtpd[16560]: sql auxprop plugin using mysql
May 22 18:45:59 myserver saslauthd[16141]: pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
May 22 18:45:59 myserver saslauthd[16141]: pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=
May 22 18:46:01 myserver saslauthd[16141]: DEBUG: auth_pam: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
May 22 18:46:01 myserver saslauthd[16141]:                 : auth failure: [user=user1] [service=smtp] [realm=myserver.nl] [mech=pam] [reason=PAM auth error]
May 22 18:46:01 myserver saslauthd[16142]: pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
May 22 18:46:01 myserver saslauthd[16142]: pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=
May 22 18:46:04 myserver saslauthd[16142]: DEBUG: auth_pam: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
May 22 18:46:04 myserver saslauthd[16142]:                 : auth failure: [user=user1] [service=smtp] [realm=myserver.nl] [mech=pam] [reason=PAM auth error]
```

(I'm logged in as `user1@myserver.nl`, and IMAP works.)

And I can see something query mysql for user `user1@myserver.nl`, but there are some many processes and daemons and configs working together, I have no idea which part fails.

A summary:

- postfix is set up to use sasl (in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and `/etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf`)
- saslauthd is set up to use pam (in `/etc/default/saslauthd`)
- pam smtp is set up to use mysql for its user db (but it never seems to?) (in `/etc/pam.d/smtp`)

The `sql_select` from `/etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf` is used to query for `user1`. I can see changes there in the mysql log.

The configured table and columns in `/etc/pam.d/smtp` are never used. Changes there don't do anything.

`testsaslauthd` only 'works' for me if I add `-f /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd/mux`, but it ALWAYS returns a `NO "authentication failed"` and NEVER queries mysql, so I've no idea how that could ever work. But the `auth.log` output is very similar to the output from Thunderbird's real request (that does trigger a mysql query/lookup):

```
May 22 18:59:56 myserver saslauthd[16756]: pam_unix(imap:auth): check pass; user unknown
May 22 18:59:56 myserver saslauthd[16756]: pam_unix(imap:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=
May 22 18:59:58 myserver saslauthd[16756]: DEBUG: auth_pam: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
May 22 18:59:58 myserver saslauthd[16756]:                 : auth failure: [user=user1@myserver.nl] [service=imap] [realm=] [mech=pam] [reason=PAM auth error]
```

And then there's the password hash. I've set up Dovecot to only accept SSL and use the plaintext password (`users.clear`). I don't know if the hashed password (`users.crypt`) is correct, or if it's even used by Postfix. I've tried all combinations in all config files. The `auth.log` output is always the same. No details.

Thunderbird tells me it can't send the message, and then shows a kind of error message: ... "unexpected error 80004005" ... "could not be sent for an unknown reason". That doesn't seem like a wrong password error, but an internal server error somewhere. But no horrible error messages in the logs...

After adding some debug level somewhere (sorry I can't remember, so many config files!!) the syslog contains more on the smtp connection:

```
May 22 19:10:45 myserver postfix/submission/smtpd[16779]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS read finished
...
May 22 19:10:45 myserver postfix/submission/smtpd[16779]: Anonymous TLS connection established from ip-1.2.3.4.ip.myisp.net[4.3.2.1]: TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (128/128 bits)
...
May 22 19:10:45 myserver postfix/submission/smtpd[16779]: Read 22 chars: EHLO [192.168.0.101]??
...
May 22 19:10:45 myserver postfix/submission/smtpd[16779]: Read 49 chars: AUTH PLAIN AHVzZXIxQG15c2VydmVyLm5sAHBp
May 22 19:10:48 myserver postfix/submission/smtpd[16779]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed
May 22 19:10:48 myserver postfix/submission/smtpd[16779]: warning: ip-1.2.3.4.ip.myisp.net[4.3.2.1]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: authentication failure
May 22 19:10:48 myserver postfix/submission/smtpd[16779]: Write 64 chars: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed:
...
May 22 19:10:48 myserver postfix/submission/smtpd[16779]: Read 12 chars: AUTH LOGIN??
May 22 19:10:48 myserver postfix/submission/smtpd[16779]: Write 18 chars: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6??
...
May 22 19:10:50 myserver postfix/submission/smtpd[16779]: warning: ip-1.2.3.4.ip.myisp.net[4.3.2.1]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
May 22 19:10:50 myserver postfix/submission/smtpd[16779]: Write 64 chars: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed:
...
May 22 19:10:52 myserver postfix/submission/smtpd[16779]: disconnect from ip-1.2.3.4.ip.myisp.net[4.3.2.1] ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=0/2 quit=1 commands=4/6
```

The `EHLO` + `AUTH PLAIN ...` are interesting... The EHLO isn't `myserver`? The logged base64 is cut off? And then "Password verification failed", but no details on which part failed.

I can't find any more debugging than this. syslog, mail log, auth log, mysql log. All the config files are huge, so I didn't add most. I followed http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/ pretty exactly, and verified every step several times, so that's what I got. EXCEPT clear vs crypt, I've changed that around a few times.

Any brilliant ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think it works... Omg that feels good! Now to figure out where to disable this insane amount of debugging...

The solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/417882/43000

And I also changed from PAM to Postfix's SQL plugin ('auxprop sql'?): http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#auxprop_sql because I don't want encrypted passwords.

And now instead of

```
postfix/submission/smtpd[16560]: Read 49 chars: AUTH PLAIN AHVzZXIxQG15c2VydmVyLm5sAHBp
postfix/submission/smtpd[16560]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed
postfix/submission/smtpd[16560]: warning: ip-1-2-3-4.ip.prioritytelecom.net[4.3.2.1]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: authentication failure
postfix/submission/smtpd[16560]: Write 64 chars: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed:
```

I get

```
postfix/submission/smtpd[23504]: Read 49 chars: AUTH PLAIN AHVzZXIxQG15c2VydmVyLm5sAHBp
postfix/submission/smtpd[23504]: Write 37 chars: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful??
```

I don't know what's up with the `??`, but yes, it seems to be succesful.

It even copied the sent mail to the Sent mail folder a few times, but not anymore (Thunderbird hangs forever).